# Java loosing part of input streambuffer

Tags: java, xml, linux, inputstream

I'm currently working on a project to parse weather data from an XML input stream. However I'm experiencing a strange bug related to Linux.

When running the server software that's receiving the input stream on Windows, everything works like a charm. However when running the server on Linux, the following bug presents itself. After receiving a couple messages correctly, the third or so message will be corrupted because half of the input buffer will be "lost".

This issue only occurs in the following situations:

```
[Platform]   [Origin of XML stream]   [Error occurs]
Windows      localhost                No
Windows      remote                   No
Linux        localhost                No
Linux        remote                   Yes
```

I'm using the following code to receive the XML stream.

```
private Document getXML() throws JDOMException
{
    SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
    try {
        // Get the input stream.
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
        String xmlstream = "";
        String line;
        while (!(line = in.readLine()).contains("</MEASUREMENT>")){
            xmlstream += line;
        }
        xmlstream += "</MEASUREMENT></WEATHERDATA>";
        System.out.println("XML DATA:" + xmlstream);
        Document xmlDocument = builder.build(new StringReader(xmlstream));
        return xmlDocument;
    } catch (IOException | NullPointerException e) {
        // Socket closes.
        System.out.println("Client disconnected!");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here is an example of the received data:

```
XML DATA:<?xml version="1.0"?><WEATHERDATA> <MEASUREMENT>       <STN>726030</STN>       <DATE>2018-01-27</DATE>     <TIME>13:42:01</TIME>   <TEMP>-2.8</TEMP>       <DEWP>-2.7</DEWP>       <STP>1014.1</STP>       <SLP>1019.3</SLP>       <VISIB>8.2</VISIB>      <WDSP>29.0</WDSP>       <PRCP>0.02</PRCP>       <SNDP>0.0</SNDP><FRSHTT>110000</FRSHTT>     <CLDC>77.1</CLDC>       <WNDDIR>191</WNDDIR></MEASUREMENT></WEATHERDATA>

XML DATA:<?xml version="1.0"?><WEATHERDATA> <MEASUREMENT>       <STN>726030</STN>       <DATE>2018-01-27</DATE>     <TIME>13:42:02</TIME>   <TEMP>-0.7</TEMP>       <DEWP>-3.5</DEWP>       <STP>1014.2</STP>       <SLP>1019.2</SLP>       <VISIB>8.3</VISIB>      <WDSP>28.9</WDSP>       <PRCP>0.02</PRCP>       <SNDP>0.0</SNDP><FRSHTT>110000</FRSHTT>     <CLDC>77.2</CLDC>       <WNDDIR>191</WNDDIR></MEASUREMENT></WEATHERDATA>

XML DATA:/DATE>     <TIME>13:42:02</TIME>       <TEMP>-9.4</TEMP>   <DEWP>-13.5</DEWP>      <STP>1005.1</STP>       <SLP>1013.2</SLP>       <VISIB>22.8</VISIB>     <WDSP>12.8</WDSP>       <PRCP>0.25</PRCP>       <SNDP>8.3</SNDP>        <FRSHTT>111000</FRSHTT>     <CLDC>50.0</CLDC>       <WNDDIR>311</WNDDIR></MEASUREMENT></WEATHERDATA>
```

As you can see, the first two messages are received in it's entirity, however the third message randomly starts in the middle of the stream.

Comment: Problem doesn't occur on the localhost. Are you sure there are no connection problems between stream source and your remote linux server? I assume you're using same JRE in all cases?

Comment: There shouldn't be any problems with the network "dropping packets."  CRC checking and sequence numbers in the TCP layer should prevent that from happening.  It almost certainly has to be a bug in the server side software, either OP, or possibly some bug in the OS version software or JVM.  Should try a different Linux box to test.  It's possible too that there's a bug in the client side that only manifests when connected to the Linux system for some reason.

Comment: I've tried a few more things and it seems the algorithm for "cutting" the steam is not working properly on some systems. What would in your opinion be the best way to split an XML stream at the right moment? I can give more technical information about the XML stream if needed.